# matching between sql column and texfield input using php

Tags: php, html, sql

im trying to match my textfield input of a "coupon_code" to a value in a sql table. i have three files that connect to each other. also, there should be an alert if the texfield matches.

HTML: (membership.php)

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require_once('membership.vc.php');
?>
       <form>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col col-md-8">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" name="promocode3" placeholder="ENTER PROMO CODE">
          </div>
          <div class="col col-md-4">
                  <input type="submit" class="btn color-white mwc-orange-background-color" name="redeem" value="REDEEM">
         </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

PHP: (membership.vc.php)

```
<?php

  require_once($routePath . "_mc/PromoCode.mc.php");
  $mcPromoCode = new PromoCode_MC();

  if (isset($_POST['redeem']) && $_POST['redeem'] == 'REDEEM'){

    $pcode3_txtfield = $_POST['promocode3'];

    $rowpcode3 = $mcPromoCode->SelectPromoCode3($db, $p3id);
    $pcode3 = $rowpcode3['coupon_code'];


    if ($pcode3_txtfield == $pcode3 ){
      echo "<script>
      alert('There are no fields to generate a report');
      window.location.href='admin/ahm/panel';
      </script>";
    }
  }

    ?>
```

SQL Function: (PromoCode.mc.php)

```
<?php Class PromoCode_MC {

      public function SelectPromoCode3($db, $p3id) {
        $stmt = $db->prepare(
          "   SELECT *
              FROM mywhitecard.promocode_3
              WHERE p3id = :p3id ");

        $stmt->bindValue(':p3id', $p3id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $row; } } ?>
```

[image: table]

$pcode3 should get the column and $pcode3_txtfield should get the textfield input, which part did i do wrong? since there is no alert popup.

UPDATE: tried to do what the comments said, i thought using the primary key of the table will work but still no effect

UPDATE: i tried:

```
<?php Class PromoCode_MC {

      public function SelectPromoCode3($db, $pcode3_txtfield) {
        $stmt = $db->prepare(
          "   SELECT *
              FROM mywhitecard.promocode_3
              WHERE pcode3_txtfield = :coupon_code ");

        $stmt->bindValue(':pcode3_txtfield', $pcode3_txtfield, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $row; }

       } ?>
```

no effect

Comment: There's no parameter `:coupon_code`. There's no `WHERE` at all. SQL is powerful but not clairvoyant.

Comment: `$pcode3_txtfield = $_POST['redeem']`
Here you are grabbing the value of the submit button.  Instead, you want to grab the value of the text input field.

Comment: did both comments, still no alert popup on matching "coupon_codes"

Comment: In the textfield you are typing the promo code so in your query you should look for the promo code instead of the ID of the promo code.

Comment: You don't seem to be setting the value of `$coupon_code` before you pass it to `SelectPromoCode3`

Comment: would like to see examoples

Comment: `$rowpcode3 = $mcPromoCode->SelectPromoCode3($db, $coupon_code);`  Right, to add to the previous 2 comments, you would want to pass `$pcode3_txtfield` instead of `$coupon_code`, right?

Comment: im sorry i dont get the explanation, should i replace my "coupon_code"?

Comment: You are sending the variable `$p3id` to your SelectPromoCode3 function, but I don't see that being set to anything.  I think what you want to do is send the value of the text input box right?  So you'd want to send `$pcode3_txtfield`.

Comment: `$rowpcode3 = $mcPromoCode->SelectPromoCode3($db, $pcode3_txtfield);`

Comment: will my "function SelectPromoCode3" get any changes?

Comment: @dmikester1 I compared my texfield input to the coupon_code column using WHERE, still no effect but am i on the right track? updated my question as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187076/discussion-between-dmikester1-and-jeremiah-canuto).